having problem with plus/minus buttons in input type number
I have this dynamic input fields table with dynamic add / remove rows and it works great, instead of the default increment and Decrement arrows inside input number  i added plus/ minus buttons but i'm having problem to make it work like i had before with the up down arrows, i appreciate if you could help me.


const 
  myTable_tBody = document.querySelector('#my-table tbody')
, templateRow   = document.querySelector('#template-row')
, myTable_Total = document.querySelector('#my-table tfoot input[name="anstotal"]')
  ;
AddNewRow(); // first attempt

document.querySelector('#btn-add-row').addEventListener('click', AddNewRow);

myTable_tBody.addEventListener('input', setTotals);

myTable_tBody.addEventListener('click', e =>
  {
  if (e.target.tagName == "BUTTON") setTotals();
  if (!e.target.matches('button[name="delete-row"]')) return;
  e.target.closest('tr').remove();
  setTotals();
  });

function setTotals()
  {
  let Total = 0;
  [...myTable_tBody.rows].forEach( r => 
    {
    let inTotal = r.querySelector('input[name="qty"]').valueAsNumber
                * +r.querySelector('select[name="sel"]').value;

    r.querySelector('input[name="total"]').value = inTotal;
    Total += inTotal;
    });
  myTable_Total.value = Total;
  }
  
function AddNewRow()
  {
  if (myTable_tBody.rows.length < 4)
    myTable_tBody.append( document.importNode(templateRow.content, true) );
  else
    alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 4.");
  }
table {
  font-family     : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size       : 14px;
  background      : darkblue;
  border-collapse : separate;
  border-spacing  : 1px;
  }
th {
  background-color : aquamarine;
  padding          : .8em .4em;
  }
td {
  background-color : whitesmoke;
  padding          : .8em .4em;
  text-align       : right;
  }

/* hide the delete button in case of only one row. */ 
table#my-table tbody tr:only-child button[name="delete-row"] {
  visibility : hidden;
  }
input[name="qty"] {
  width: 90px;
}

.form__number {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: var(--size-min-width);
    width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-input-number-border);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.form__number_input-number {
    display: flex;
    width: var(--size-min-width); 
  width: 30%;
  height: var(--size);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    appearance: textfield;
  border: 0;
  
}
.form__number_input-number::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.form__number_input-number::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    display: none;
}
.form__number_button {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #fff0;
  width: var(--size);
  color: var(--color-input-number-button-fg);
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.form__number_button:hover {
  color: var(--color-link);
}
.form__number_button:active
,.form__number_button:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
.form__number_button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
<button id="btn-add-row">Add new row</button>
<table id="my-table">
  <thead> <tr><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th><th></th></tr> </thead>
  <tbody> </tbody>
  <tfoot> <tr><td colspan="3"> TOTAL = <input type="text" name="anstotal" value="0" readonly></td><td></td></tr> </tfoot>
</table>

<template id="template-row">
  <tr> 
    <td> 
    <button 
      class="form__number_button form__number_button-minus" 
      type="button" 
      onclick="this.nextElementSibling.stepDown(); this.nextElementSibling;"
    >
    -
    </button>
       <input type="number" name="qty" value="0" min="0">  
    <button type="button" 
      class="form__number_button form__number_button form__number_button-plus" 
      onclick="this.previousElementSibling.stepUp(); this.previousElementSibling;"
    >
     +
    </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="sel" >
        <option value="0" disabled selected>Choose a price</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>      
    </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="total" value="0" readonly> </td>
    <td> <button name="delete-row">Delete</button> </td>
  </tr>
</template>




In what way does your code currently not work as expected?  What specific problem are you stuck on?

as previously mentioned i add the plus /minus buttons but it doesn't add to the input value and i get this error :Uncaught TypeError: this.previousElementSibling.onchange is not a function.

(1) It does modify the input value, at least in my browser.  (2) Then onchange is not a function.  Why are you trying to call it?  What happens if you don't call it?

when i removed 'onchange' it works now but now the calculations not working it supposed to multiply the input value with select option value and output the subtotal and grand total.

The example in the question still clearly shows the error you were previously asking about.  If you're trying to ask about some other problem entirely, please update the question to demonstrate that problem and indicate specifically what debugging you have done and what operation isn't doing what you expect.  If you're not familiar with the development/debugging tools in your browser, now is a great time to start.

i updated the snippet but the calculations are not working at all.

Be specific about the problem you're trying to describe.  "The calculations" appear to work as expected for me.  What specific problem are you observing and asking about?

I guess you are trying to trigger the change event on the input when the button is pressed, but:

That's not the way to trigger an event
Even if you could trigger the event like that, there's nothing associated to the change event

You should remove both calls to .onchange() since they are invalid, then you can just call the setTotals function when a button is pressed inside the table:
myTable_tBody.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.tagName == "BUTTON") setTotals();
});

And that should work since setTotals always processes all the tables rows.
